# mdframed innertopmargin should be same to next page

Tags: mdframed

I have using `mdframed` and expecting output is same `innertopmargin space` is continued to `next page`:

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx,lipsum,mdframed,showframe}
\global\mdfdefinestyle{greenbox}{%
linecolor=white,
linewidth=0pt,%
frametitlerule=false,%
frametitlefont=\bfseries\fontsize{10}{13}\selectfont,
hidealllines=true,
backgroundcolor=green,
innertopmargin=25pt,
font=\fontsize{9}{12}\selectfont,
innerleftmargin=14pt,
innerrightmargin=14pt,
innerbottommargin=13pt
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5-7]
\begin{mdframed}[style=greenbox]
\lipsum[8-10]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual, you ask a question on `mdframed` and I/we answer using `tcolorbox` ;-)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathptmx,lipsum,showframe}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{greenbox}[1][]{%
  enhanced jigsaw,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  boxsep=1pt,
  top=25pt,
  bottom=13pt,
  left=14pt,
  right=14pt,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colback=green,
  breakable,
  parbox=false,
  #1
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Title}
\lipsum[1-4]
\lipsum[5-7]
\begin{greenbox}
\lipsum[8-10]
\end{greenbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]